# why UserManager doesn't move UpdateSecurityStampInternal call to UpdateUserAsync()?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

below is some source code of `UserManager<TUser>` https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs,559d58dbdf6e6bee

```
public class UserManager<TUser> : IDisposable where TUser : class
{
    public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> ChangeEmailAsync(TUser user, string newEmail, string token) 
    { 
        // Make sure the token is valid and the stamp matches
        if (!await VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, Options.Tokens.ChangeEmailTokenProvider, GetChangeEmailTokenPurpose(newEmail), token).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            return IdentityResult.Failed(ErrorDescriber.InvalidToken());
        }

        var store = GetEmailStore();
        await store.SetEmailAsync(user, newEmail, CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);  
        await store.SetEmailConfirmedAsync(user, true, CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user).ConfigureAwait(false);  <--------------------------------
        
        return await UpdateUserAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }  
  
    public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> ChangePhoneNumberAsync(TUser user, string phoneNumber, string token)
    {
        var store = GetPhoneNumberStore();
 
        if (!await VerifyChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user, token, phoneNumber).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            Logger.LogDebug(LoggerEventIds.PhoneNumberChanged, "Change phone number for user failed with invalid token.");
            return IdentityResult.Failed(ErrorDescriber.InvalidToken());
        }

        await store.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, phoneNumber, CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await store.SetPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user, true, CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user).ConfigureAwait(false);  // <-----------------------------------
        return await UpdateUserAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    
    protected virtual async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateUserAsync(TUser user)  
    {                                                                         
        var result = await ValidateUserAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return result;
        }
        await UpdateNormalizedUserNameAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await Store.UpdateAsync(user, CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    // ...
}
```

my question is, why not asp.net source code move the `await UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user).ConfigureAwait(false);` in update method like `ChangeEmailAsync`, `ChangePhoneNumberAsync` to `UpdateUserAsync`

```
protected virtual async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateUserAsync(TUser user)  
{                                                                         
    // ...
    await UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user).ConfigureAwait(false); <----------update SecurityStamp here
    await UpdateNormalizedUserNameAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await Store.UpdateAsync(user, CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

isn't it a better approach and reduce code duplication in `ChangeEmailAsync`, `ChangePhoneNumberAsync` etc?

Comment: you might find it repetitive but if we can see it will provide security and flexibility.updating the security stamp is super important for user safety, especially when changing sensitive info like emails or phone numbers. By placing the update in these specific methods, it ensures the security is tightened right where it's needed most.this approach gives more control. like if updating the user's profile picture also refreshed the security stamp – it could be overkill. So, by not lumping it all in `UpdateUserAsync`, they avoid unnecessary security updates for minor changes.